# FTP File upload using Java

Tags: java, ftp

hey i want to upload a file to a directory called 'screenshots' on my webserver via FTP using java. I have been using this code and it says that it stores the file successfully and connected successfully but when i check my screenshots directory via the cpanel i dont see the file that was uploaded any help?

```
 public static void uploadFilee() {
              FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
              FileInputStream fis = null;

              try {
                  client.connect("****************");
                  client.login("********", "********");
                  System.out.println("Connected Successfully");
                  String filename = "C:/Users/Christian/Desktop/screenshots/img_" +         queueInfo.get("SessionID");
                  fis = new FileInputStream(filename);

                  client.storeFile(filename, fis);
                  System.out.println("Stored File Successfully");
                  client.logout();
              } catch (IOException e) {
                  System.out.println("Error_1");
                  e.printStackTrace();
              } finally {
                  try {
                      if (fis != null) {
                          fis.close();
                      }
                      client.disconnect();
                  } catch (IOException e) {
                      System.out.println("Error_2");
                      e.printStackTrace();
                  }
              }
          }

        `
```

Comment: What does this have to do with SQL or PHP?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to review this page
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#_storeFile(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.io.InputStream)

you have your statements such as storefile in a try statement, but if they fail, they return false, not an exception.

changing your code to inspect the return values of each function should help you find where your problem lies.